# How to slice a huge image into smaller ones with 'Save for Web'

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I have a huge image (1024*256000) which I want to slice horizontally into 100 images of 1024*256.

I'm using Adobe Photoshop CS6. I created the horizontal slices with the *Slice* tool and the  *Divide* option.

*Save for web* allows me to save the images, but only at a 32.03% scale. If I try to change the *Percent* field to 100%, it gives me the following error:

```
A value between 0.01 and 32.03 is required. Closest value inserted.
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe save them out as non-save for web images first then batch them into save for web afterwards...

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop's **Save for Web has a pixel limit of 8192 pixels**. No single dimension can go above that number of pixels.

The solution is to split your image into smaller pieces all under 8192px in size. Then reconstruct the pieces in HTML/CSS in needed.

There have been a [few discussions](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/in_the_age_of_sprite_sheets_surely_its_time_to_remove_the_8192px_limit_on_save_for_web_keep_getting) regarding this limit. Until Adobe alters the application, there's not much you can to if you want to use Save for Web.

Note the discussion linked above indicated one user found success by using Save for Web and the jpg format rather than png. It seems the limitation is largely related to the png format.

You could always choose to Save As.. png or jpg rather than using Save for Web - then use some other image post processor to reduce file sizes by stripping metadata and the like (things Save for Web does).

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a hard time with this too, and I'm pretty sure I've figured it out. For whatever reason, Photoshop is having trouble because the file is so TALL. Try saving the file into two vertical sections, so that each is 50% of the original file height. When you try to save a slice for web now, it should default to 100%.